# How to throw ForbiddenException in ASP.NET Core 2 Instead of using AccessDeniedPath

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, authorize-attribute, asp.net-authorization

I am working on an ASP.NET Core 2 web application. I am handling Access Denied page for **[Authorize (roles OR policies)]** pages.

By default, Instead of showing the original URL and returning **403** status, ASP.NET Core 2.0 redirects the request to an AccessDenied page with status is **302** -> This is not what I want.

Instead of redirecting AccessDenied page. I want ASP.NET Core throws my custom **ForbiddenException** exception so I can handle unauthorized accesses like I do for Unhandled exceptions.

Here is my authentication configuration:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; // Cookies
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; // Cookies       
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; // Cookies
})
.AddCookie(options => {

    options.LoginPath = "/Auth/Login/";
    options.LogoutPath = "/Auth/Logout/";

    // I want disable this and throw ForbiddenException instead.
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Auth/AccessDenied/";  
});
```

Anyone has any help? Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code for redirecting to `AccessDeniedPath` is handled by [`CookieAuthenticationEvents.OnRedirectToAccessDenied`](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/release/2.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/Events/CookieAuthenticationEvents.cs#L57), included here for completeness:

```
public Func<RedirectContext<CookieAuthenticationOptions>, Task> OnRedirectToAccessDenied { get; set; } = context =>
{
    if (IsAjaxRequest(context.Request))
    {
        context.Response.Headers["Location"] = context.RedirectUri;
        context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
    }
    else
    {
        context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
    }
    return Task.CompletedTask;
};
```

In order to override this behavior, you can provide your own implementation of `OnRedirectToAccessDenied`, that can either write to the response or, in your case, throw an exception. To do that, you can use something like the following:

```
services.AddAuthentication(...)
    .AddCookie(options => {
        // ...
        options.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = context => {
            // Your code here.
            // e.g.
            throw new YouAreNotWelcomeHereException();
        };
    });
```

Here, `context` is an instance of [`RedirectContext`](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/release/2.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication/Events/RedirectContext.cs#L11), which (through its inheritance tree), contains properties such as:

- `HttpContext`
- `Request`
- `Response`
- `Properties` (type: [`AuthenticationProperties`](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/release/2.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions/Authentication/AuthenticationProperties.cs#L13))

Using these properties, you can obtain any information you need about the incoming request. You can also write your own response, etc.